# How do I get the Q42 achievement?

Tags: achievements, 0h-h1

The achievement text just says "Cheers from team Q42".

How do I earn this achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to play 42 games. In the leaderboards there's a section called "Games played" that tracks it.